# Pass website url as an argument in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have three domains like `www.example1.com, www.example2.com and www.example3.com`.

i have pointed these domains to **www.adminwebsite.com** through CNAME, A and Name Server.

It is working fine.

I need to redirect

```
www.example1.com
```

to

> www.adminwebsite.com/index.php?website="www.example1.com"

Is it possible through .htacces or any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but should work, give it a go:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example1\.com)$
RewriteRule $^ http://www.adminwebsite.com/index.php?website=%1 [R=302,L]
```

Keep in mind that if your adminwebsite domain is not the default domain of the server you will still need to configure the example1 domain on the HTTP server otherwise it won't work or if you have cPanel you will have to create an addon with it.